# How to change keyboard without using raspi-config?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, keyboard, locale

I have HypriotOS running which is a **Raspbian Stretch** version

```
uname -a
Linux test 4.14.34-hypriotos+ #2 Sun APr 22 15:29:32 UTC 2018 armv61 GNU/Linux


lsb_release
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description Raspbian GNU/Linux 0.4 (stretch)
```

I wont configure the keyboard layout without using the regular `raspi-config` tool..
What I try to achieve is, that I flash the HypriotOS with german language already set. At the latest after the first reboot...

I tried a lot of options, no one of them worked, only the terminal language is german now.
But the "Z" is still on the key "Y" and vice versa: Following code shows all my approaches as well the content of the files:

**BTW**: The ONLY WAY I GOT IT WORKING WAS BY USING the `raspi-config`.

**localectl status**

```
System Locale: LAG=de_DE.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: de-latin1nexport
   X11 Layout: DE
    X11 Model: pc105
  X11 Variant: nodeadkeys
```

**/etc/vconsole.conf**

`KEYMAP=de-latin1-nodeadkeys`

**cat /etc/locale.conf**

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
export LC_DATE=de_DE.utf8
export LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.utf8
export LC_TIME=de_DE.utf8
export LANG=de_DE.utf8
```

**/etc/default/keyboard**

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT=de
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS=""
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

I tried that one too: https://wiki.archlinux.de/title/Arch_Linux_auf_Deutsch_stellen#Grundkonfiguration (It didn't work either)

`ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Vienna /etc/localtime`

And that:

- `sudo localectl set-x11-keymap de pc105`
- `sudo localectl --no-convert set-keymap de-latin1-nodeadkeys`
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data`
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
- `sudo localectl --no-convert set-keymap de-latin1-nodeadkeys`
- `sudo localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap de pc105 nodeadkeys`
- `sudo service keyboard-setup restart`
- `sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8`
- `sudo locale-gen de`
- `sudo update-locale de`
- `sudo update-locale de_DE.UTF-8`
- `sudo loadkeys de`

What else could I try?
Any help would be appreciated

Thank you very much

Comment: Did you try `dpkg-reconfigure locales`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -y xinput-calibrator
sudo apt-get install -y console-data
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive keyboard-configuration
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive console-data
sudo loadkeys de
```

Comment: Please accept your answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again after years.

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type

**/etc/default/keyboard**

and change:

```
 XKBLAYOUT="xx"
```

[Choose xx valid code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes).

Example:

XKBLAYOUT="US"

Cheers